# Reading single character from console in java

Tags: java-io

How to read single character from console in java...??
can it done without BufferedReader..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using:

```
int byte = system.in.read();
char singleChar = (char)byte;
```

should read a single byte from the console.

Comment: is there any reason you read the byte into an int instead of a byte?

Comment: @Shaded - Simply because when I double checked the return type of system.in.read() in the JavaDocs, the return type was listed as abstract int.

Comment: @Shaded - read() returns an int because all numeric types in Java are signed, and bytes are often conceptually unsigned. The byte type cannot conveniently represent values in the range 127-255, so an int is used instead.